# Java: for loop is not working properly

Tags: java, for-loop

Hello guys I'am beginner of the Java and my English is not good, i hope you will understand my problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int i, a, b, c, d, yil = 1999, rt = 0;


    do{
            //loop searching for 1976
            for( i = 1900; i < 2000; i++){
            //separate "i" to the digits
            a = i / 1000;
            b = i % 1000 / 100;
            c = i % 1000 % 100 / 10;
            d = i % 1000 % 100 % 10;
            rt = a + b + c + d;
            }}
            //while rt=23 and i=1976 equation will be correct then exit the loop and print the 1976.
            while( rt == yil - i );
        System.out.println("Yıl = " + i );

}
```

But when i run the program it always show 2000 not 1976.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the program, adding some trace/print statements, etc.?

Comment: I guess I am a bit lost here, you are searching for 1976 but that loop construct is odd, what is the general version of the problem?

Comment: According to the logic that is in there this is when rt = 23

RT: 23
yil - i: 50 (1950)
RT == yil-1? false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your messed increments may hide it, but you have no way out of your `for` loop. It always goes to the end, that is `i=2000`.

```
for( i = 1900; i < 2000; i++){
   ... // no break in there
}
...
System.out.println("Yıl = " + i );
```

There is no reason for having two loops in your case. It seems that what you want is

```
        int i, a, b, c, d, yil = 1999, rt = 0;
        //loop searching for 1976
        for( i = 1900; i < 2000; i++){
            //separate "i" to the digits
            a = i / 1000;
            b = i % 1000 / 100;
            c = i % 1000 % 100 / 10;
            d = i % 1000 % 100 % 10;
            rt = a + b + c + d;
            if (rt==yil-i) break;
        }
        System.out.println("Yıl = " + i );  }
```

This outputs

```
Yıl = 1976
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see, so how can i find the year experimentally? Any advise?